# Asigning values to the elements of a matrix

Tags: c++

I have been learning c++ for less than a month, and I have a problem with  assigning values to the elements of a matrix to solve the exercise which says to output pairs of integers (answers to a problem). In this exercise they provide you with any a and according to this "n" I have to build a matrix such that it consists of floor(n/2)*(n-floor(n/2)) pairs where in the first column each of the first floor(n/2) integers are repeated (n-floor(n/2)) times (the first half of n so that each element of the first half is paired with each element if the second half of n consecutive integers). I am very sorry for asking such a long question but it is very important to me!

I tried to create to vectors assign the elements to to columns separately but the program just asks me for the value of n and does not do anything after I press enter

```cpp
>#include <iostream>
>#include <vector>
>using namespace std;
> int main()
> {
>  int n;
>  cin >> n;
>  int a, b;
>  a=floor(n / 2);
>  b=n - a;
>  vector<int> A(a);
>  for(int i = 0; i <= a - 1; ++){
>  A[i] = i + 1;
>   }
>  vector<int> B(b);
>  for(int i = 0; i < b; i++) {
>  B[i] = a + i + 1;
>  }
>  int m;
>  m = a * b;
>  vector<int> C[m][2];
>  for(int i = 0; i < a; i++) {
>  for (int = 0; j < b; j++) {
>  C[j][0] = A[i];
>  }
>  for(int i = 0; i < b; i++) {
>   for(int j = 0; j <b; j++) {
>    C[i][1] = B[j];
>   }
> return 0;
>}

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/198cW.jpg
```

Comment: This question needs more details. At a bare minimum, include some of the actual code you've written that isn't doing what you expected. It would also help to give an example of what the expected output is for some sample input, because frankly the description is fairly hard to follow.

Comment: Please take a look at the section on [formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). Ideally, you want code that can be copied and pasted into someone else's environment and immediately compiled. All those `>`s make that harder. Also prefer directly copying and pasting code yourself, because even after removing those this code still can't compile. It has errors like `for(int = 0; ...)` where the declaration `int = 0` is invalid and mismatched `{` and `}`s. Since your code has been compiling, this question's code must be similar but not identical.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly you're trying to make a pair of numbers given n such that the pair(A,B) satisfies this (A=1..(n/2),B=the remaining half). Example: n=4 generates:
(1, 3)
(1, 4)
(2, 3)
(2, 4)
If that's the case, this code should do just that. In the future, please ensure to share the current source code that the issue stems from and maybe even the question itself with example output.

```
#include <iostream>
    #include <vector>
    
    int main() {
        int n;
        std::cout << "Enter value of n: ";
        std::cin >> n;
    
        int firstHalf = n / 2;
        int secondHalf = n - firstHalf;
    
        std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> matrix;
    
        for (int i = 1; i <= firstHalf; ++i) {
            for (int j = firstHalf + 1; j <= n; ++j) {
                matrix.push_back(std::make_pair(i, j));
            }
        }
    
        std::cout << "Generated matrix:" << std::endl;
        for (const auto& pair : matrix) {
            std::cout << "(" << pair.first << ", " << pair.second << ")" << std::endl;
        }
    
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much! For the whole hour tried to do it myself but after typing your code it worked!